# android Opencv based on Float instead of Double

Tags: android, performance, opencv, arm, neon

Floating point operations(compered to Doubles) are much faster on arm architectures and other than that NEON doesn't support doubles. So why isn't opencv4android based on float instead of double to offer a better performance ?

As an example of better performance I could mention warpPerspective (ImgProc). It was too slow (around 100 ms) but then I created my own version based on floats and voila it took only 5 ms.(not rebuilt as part of opencv but as part of my own app/lib)

I can not fork and build my own version of opencv based on float because I'll lose the advantage of some closed-source optimization which according to my testing is really important. (My own builds of opencv (with lots of optimization flags) resulted in 200-300 ms for warpPrespective!)

Comment: Your question sounds more like an answer.

Comment: This should be asked here: http://answers.opencv.org/questions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a classical example of engineering trade-offs between code maintainability and performance optimization.

Code that has undergone extreme performance optimization toward one set of goals (and as a result, diverges significantly from its original source code) typically cannot be re-optimized toward a different set of goals.

One has to go back to the original "clean, maintainable" source code version, and begin a new effort on extreme performance optimization.

The performance of ARM architecture (and NEON acceleration) has changed a lot in the recent years, in ways that exceeded the expectations of seasoned industry analysts. So, please give OpenCV some love, and considering that not many people in the software world have the full skill set to develop the SIMD code inside OpenCV, please give some serious thoughts to ways in which you can contribute to OpenCV.

As a reminder, the typical `warpPerspective` (used in the SSE2 pipeline, not sure about whether it's applicable to the NEON pipeline) consists of two steps. In the first step, a matrix of subsampling coordinates are generated from the perspective matrix, in a format similar to the output of `convertMaps`.  In the second step, each pixel value in the output matrix is sampled (with interpolation) from the input image using the matrix of sampling coordinates from the first step, similar to how `remap` works.

This implementation strategy is chosen for its reasons, but apparently the decision was made more than a decade ago, based on the hardware that was available back then. Notably, the ARM-NEON architecture probably did not have any influence on the choice of this strategy.

(Back then, nobody would have considered using OpenCV to dewarp images of 32768 x 32768 pixels; the first choice would have gone to some niche GIS imaging software. Things have changed.)